# Error in pandas.loc calculation - Copy of a sliced dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have two pandas dataframes, one named df1 and another named df2:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PERCENTAGE': [0.35,0.1105,0.0487,0.98],})

df2 = df1.loc[df1['PERCENTAGE'] > 0.4]
```

I'm trying to create a new column in df2 using this code:

```
df2['NEW_COLUMN'] = 1 - df2['PERCENTAGE']
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\PATH: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Is there a way to solve this without having to build this column directly in df1?

Answer (score 0):

Lets Try `df.loc[Query,Column]`

```
m=df1.PERCENTAGE>0.4
df1.loc[m,'NewColumn']=1-df1.loc[m,'PERCENTAGE']
df2=df1.dropna()




     PERCENTAGE  NewColumn
3        0.98       0.02
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want because df2 should be a different dataframe, with only observations where percentage is > 0.4. And in that dataframe, create a new column like the one you created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works, but I was looking for a more elegant way of doing it, otherwise I would do that column in df1 and then just filter the > 0.4 as df2.

Comment: Humbled by the opportunity to answer  your question. Keep coding

Comment: Hmm, it's just that I thought that you should only up vote when the answer is a solution, hope my "thank you" didn't bother you.

Comment: Keep well and keep coding. Coding is fun